# Scheme Test cases

Tags: scheme

I was asked to create a function that takes 2 functions as parameters and an integer. The functions are supposed to check for conditions, if they are met then it evaluates to true or false.

Here is my code, but how do I test my code. What parameters do I put into the function to test? I tried `(find harmonic even? 6)` and it gives me an error. Harmonic is a function that takes the nth number in harmonic and sums them all up. Can someone please help? What test cases can I use?

```
(define (find sequence test n)
  (define (helper x found)
    (let ((fx (sequence x)))
      (if (test fx)
          (if (= (+ found 1) n) fx
              (helper (+ x 1) (+ found 1)))
          (helper (+ x 1) found)))) (helper 1 0))
```

Comment: I see that you are new to Stack Overflow. The downvotes you are getting may be discouraging. To increase your chances of getting proper answers and to avoid downvotes in the future, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: It's too difficult to help you because there isn't enough clear information about what you want to do.